# Forcing Azure Emulator to run on port 80 / 443

Tags: azure

Is there a way to force azure emulator to run on port 80/443 and even better on IIS 8 instead of IIS Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator will use the ports specified by the protect as long as they are available (i.e. not used by any other process)

If they are not available it will increment the port number until it finds an available one.

If you're already running IIS, 80 and 443 are probably taken and so 81 and 444 will be used if available and so on.

So - in order to run the emulator on 80 and 443 you must turn off IIS, exit the emulator (shutdown is not enough) and restart the emulator to allow it to capture ports 80 and 443.

Read more about it [here](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/windows-azure-compute-emulator-and-ports/)

Comment: i saw it is really incrementing the ports, though i'm still trying to figure out why after changing the bindings of the default web site of the iis ,shutting down the emulator + exiting its still not choosing to take the correct port but actually it chose to increment again.

i also changed its settings to run on iis instead of iis express, but still its not using the correct ports.

Comment: Were you able to confirm that IIS no longer uses these ports? I would check that it responds to the new bindings and then restart all the application pools, or better yet - the computer :-)

Comment: i thought about restarting the application pools, but i gave up to a good night sleep. :)

i tried this morning, and it worked after restarting the application pools, i saw that iis is using port 80 on 0.0.0.0 under PID 4 which is the system.

Thanks Yossi!

Comment: i just realized that 443 was ok but 80 wasn't, found out that stopping Web Deployment Agent Service solves it:
http://trustedcode.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/sneaky-port-binding.html